# mapping deeply nested element with namespaces while using happymapper

Tags: xml, mapping, ruby-on-rails-6

In a Ruby on Rails 6 environment, I'm using happyMapper to map some xml files.

Here is a fragment of one XML file

```
<Tag>
    <ClassName>Codice Fiscale</ClassName>
    <xs:xsd xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:simpleType name="Codice Fiscale">
            <xs:restriction base="X4006E1450246">
                <xs:pattern value="\p{L}{6,6}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV][0-9LMNPQRSTUV]\p{L}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV][0-9LMNPQRSTUV]\p{L}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV][0-9LMNPQRSTUV][0-9LMNPQRSTUV]\p{L}"/>
                <xs:pattern value="\p{L}{6,6}\d\d\p{L}\d\d\p{L}\d\d\d\p{L}"/>
                <xs:pattern value="\d{11,11}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:xsd>
    <Multiplicity>
        <MinOccurrence>1</MinOccurrence>
        <MaxOccurrence>1</MaxOccurrence>
    </Multiplicity>
</Tag>
```

Everything run fine, except that I cannot correctly parse the `xs:xsd` element: it always returns `[""]`.

Maybe, part of the complexity is in the fact that I would like to map several `xs:pattern` sub-element  in one `has-many :patterns` element.

Here is my class declaration:

```
class Tag

    include HappyMapper

    #register_namespace 'nonamespace', ''
    register_namespace 'xs', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

    tag "Tag"

    element   :class_name, String, tag: 'ClassName'

    has_one   :min_occurrence, Integer, tag: 'Multiplicity/MinOccurrence'

    has_many  :patterns, String, tag: 'xs:xsd/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:pattern'
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct definition for patterns is

```
has_many  :patterns, String, tag: 'xsd/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:pattern/@value', namespace: 'xs'
```